# notNullObjectForKey addition - do we need this or is there a non-category solution

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm just looking at some code we have so this question is asked from one of ignorance and making sure I fully understand what is going on. We have a couple of apps that always include a category with the following:

header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDictionary (additions)
-(id)notNullObjectForKey:(id)aKey;
@end
```

implementation file:

```
#import "NSDictionary+Additions.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (additions)

-(id)notNullObjectForKey:(id)aKey
{
    id obj=[self objectForKey:aKey];
    if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
        return nil;
    }
    return obj;
}

@end
```

We use this for JSON parsing to protect against malformed data like so (in Item.h) - presumably.

```
-(id)initWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
{
    self.name=[attributes notNullObjectForKey:@"name"];
    return self;
}
```

Is there a way to do this without having to add this to every project? Is all this checking for is if the key exists and if not, return NSNull?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code checks to see if the object is equal to `NSNull` and, if it is, returns nil. This prevents the rest of the code from needing to check. If the value doesn't exist for that key or it is not `NSNull` then the code doesn't change anything.

There are other ways in which this could be done but a category is a fine solution. Most other solutions would be more contrived and/or less easy to read.